# Bootstrap 4 dropdown breaks when importing bootstrap in Angular 7

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I'm having this issue in an Angular 7 app. I **was not** able to reproduce it with pure Bootstrap CSS/JS and Popper.js.

I'm trying to use vanilla Bootstrap JS and jQuery because I need Bootstrap's toasts and the other libs (`ng-bootstrap` and `ngx-bootstrap`) don't support toasts for the moment.

#### Minimal (non) working example

https://github.com/Crocmagnon/angular-bootstrap4-dropdown-issue

Run it with `npm run start`

#### Link to issue in Popper.js repo

I tried to ask the developer but he's clueless : https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/issues/748

#### Steps to reproduce the problem

To reproduce with the example :

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
git clone https://github.com/Crocmagnon/angular-bootstrap4-dropdown-issue.git
cd angular-bootstrap4-dropdown-issue
npm i
ng serve
```

To reproduce from scratch :

1. Create an angular app with ng-cli
2. Install bootstrap and bootstrap types:

   - `npm install --save bootstrap @types/bootstrap`.
   - `@types/bootstrap` requires `popper.js` as a dependency.
3. Include Bootstrap 4 CSS and JS files
4. Include Popper JS UMD file
5. **Add `import 'bootstrap';` somewhere to tell typescript that the jQuery `.tooltip()` function exists**
6. Try to use Bootstrap 4 dropdown in navbar

Relevant excerpt from `angular.json` :

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
  "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/util.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/alert.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/button.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/carousel.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/collapse.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/modal.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/tab.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/toast.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/popover.js"
]
```

#### What is the expected behavior?

The dropdown should toggle

#### What went wrong?

The dropdown doesn't toggle at all

#### Comments

I tried to include Popper ESM files in my `angular.json` file. Everything now works fine, except that I get an error in the console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Do I miss something here ?

## Edit

It seems that this statement in `main.ts` breaks the dropdown :

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

However, if I remove it, Typescript screams when I want to do some Bootstrap jQuery like displaying toasts or tooltips :

```
$(() => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: You can make your life easier by using an Angular implementation of Bootstrap, like [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).

Comment: Can you clarify why you are attempting to use Bootstrap JS + jQuery (and related modules) with Angular instead of using components/directive/modules from a library such as [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/) that's specifically designed/developed to work with Angular lifecycle/rendering? You will experience a variety of issues attempting to use raw Bootstrap/jQuery as rendering works pretty differently in frameworks like Angular.

Comment: `ng-bootstrap` and `ngx-bootstrap` don't have toasts, which I need in another part of my app, that's why I went with vanilla Bootstrap JS + jQuery. I'm adding this to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187444/discussion-between-gabriel-and-nisharg-shah).

Comment: edited question to mention `import 'bootstrap';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having here is because of the typescript compiler. To circumvent that, you could initialize the tooltips and other elements in a basic JS file. You will need to import this file so create it either in the assets folder (and link it in your `index.html`) or in another location and mention it in the `scripts` part of your `angular.json`.

To initialize tooltips, the content of this JS file would be :

```
$(() => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

This would initialize all tooltips when the document gets ready.

If you want to do that at a specific moment in the Angular flow, wrap the call in a function like so :

```
function tooltip() {
  $(() => {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  })
}
```

To call it in a Typescript file, you'll need to first declare the function. For example, to initialize the tooltips in `ngOnInit()` :

```
declare function tooltip();
ngOnInit() {
  tooltip();
}
```

This way you won't need to `import 'bootstrap';` anywhere and so you won't break your other components.

Answer (score 0):

I am using latest version of angular-cli.

First of all, download [my Github project](https://github.com/NishargShah/angular-help) and in `cmd` run `npm install` (so all dependency is added to your system) and after run `ng-serve`, this will Navigate to http://localhost:4200/.

if you done that, your problem is solved.

if you want to use `jquery-syntex` in your project.

type this commands in `cmd`

```
npm install jquery --save 
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

and add this syntax in your app.component.ts

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

**2nd Question**

use `ngx-bootstrap`, if you want to use `tooltip` on your device.

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue. Without the `import 'bootstrap'` call somewhere in the code, the compiler complains about `.tooltip()` not being a function

Comment: you can use `ngx-bootstrap` for that

Comment: by the way you are asking different question, so if you like my answer, don't forgot to consider up-vote and check my answer as best answer for you by clicking on right arrow, thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't mixing a library like ng-bootstrap and vanilla bootstrap CSS/JS break everything ?
I don't feel like asking two different questions : I want to use vanilla bootstrap with angular, however I'm running into some issues with combining tooltips and dropdowns.

Comment: If you are at beginner state in your project, change into ng-bootstrap. I ask same question about dropdown in SO, you are saw that in my profile

Comment: Dont mix both library because it creates problem, i experienced it !!

Comment: Again, `ng-bootstrap` and `ngx-bootstrap` don't support toasts, which I need.

Comment: You can also create toast using card and for close button use `data-dismiss`

Comment: I have solution, if you want to do with Bootstrap library ( without using `ng-bootstrap` and `ngx-bootstrap` ). I will add new answer after 6hr because i have exam today, so wait for while