# How can i make my carousel work in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have a carousel that I copied from the documentation of [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/) but it only shows one image. How can I make my carousel show all images?.Im new using Angular

Here's my code:

```html
<div class=" bg-success text-white py-5 text-center">
    <h1 >header</h1>
</div>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="./assets/images/leadlogic_1.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="./assets/images/leadlogic_2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="./assets/images/leadlogic_3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If  you are suing pure html, what you are missing is jquery, `https://jsfiddle.net/Lmbocf9n/`, If you are using angular, better follow this `https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples`

Comment: I saw the web site but dont know how to properly use it, im new using angular

Comment: If you are referring to ng bootstrap, Follow instructions here first, `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` then try to follow `https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/carousel-basic.ts`

Comment: you can use my answer for some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407072/bootstrap-4-dropdown-breaks-when-importing-bootstrap-in-angular-7/54421555#54421555

Comment: It works with the @SupunDeSilva answer

Comment: do try https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works doing the things that says the next link `https://uxworks.online/how-to-add-dynamic-carousel-in-angular-in-simple-steps/`

Answer (score 1):

use ngx-bootstrap Carousel Component :
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps to work bootstrap carousel in your Angular project

**Install below dependencies**

```
npm i bootstrap
npm i jquery
npm i popper.js@1.14.3
```

Then add css and js file in your angular.json file.

In **styles** section add **bootstrap.min.css**

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
]
```

In the **scripts** section add jquery, bootstrap and popper js files

```
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"   ,
  "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
]
```

Now you can add your bootstrap carousel in your template file. Also you need to change **data-slide-to="0"** to **[attr.data-slide-to]="0"**

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `ngb-carousel` for lesser code

use this command to install ngx-bootstrap

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

import `ng-bootstrap` in your `module.ts` file

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

and add html code

```
    <ngb-carousel *ngIf="cars">
          <div *ngFor="let item of cars">
              <ng-template  ngbSlide>
                  <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                      <img [src]="item"  alt="Random first slide" class="mh-100" style="width: 100%; height: 35vh">
                  </div>
              </ng-template>
          </div>
    </ngb-carousel>
```

you can check out my stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngbcarouseldemo